# Как организовать работу слоя посредников (Middleware)?

Tags: php, middleware

Пытаюсь разобраться как работают посредники, хотя бы на не самом низком уровне. Для экспериментов взял готовый [компонент для работы с HTTP](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros), [роутер](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Router), [компонент для отправки/вызова посредников](https://github.com/moon-php/http-middleware).
Пример того, что получилось

```php
$request = Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals();
$routerContainer = new Aura\Router\RouterContainer();
$map = $routerContainer->getMap();
$matcher = $routerContainer->getMatcher();

// коллекция роутов приложения
$map->get('main', '/', new App\Controllers\HomeController());
$map->get('about', '/about', new App\Controllers\AboutController());

// добавляем посредников
$delegate = new Moon\HttpMiddleware\Delegate([
    new App\Middlewares\TestMiddleware(),
  ], 
  function() {
    new Zend\Diactoros\Response\HtmlResponse('<h1>alert!</h1>');
  }
);
$delegate->handle($request);

// поиск текущего роута и формирование ответа
$route = $matcher->match($request);
$response = ($route->handler)($request);

// отправка ответа на клиент
$emitter = new Zend\HttpHandlerRunner\Emitter\SapiEmitter();
$emitter->emit($response ?? new Zend\Diactoros\Response\EmptyResponse());
```

Такой способ приводит к ошибкам в недрах класса `Delegate`, которые не могут быть разрешены в попытках исправить их "в лоб".
Допускаю, что какой-то этап пропущен, но какой - никак не могу найти.

Answer (score 0):

Привожу пример со своего проекта

```
$app = new MiddlewarePipe(); // Zend\Stratigility\MiddlewarePipe
$app->pipe(new MiddlewareException($container->get(LoggerInterface::class), $prototype));
$app->pipe($container->get(MiddlewareSettings::class));
$app->pipe($container->get(MiddlewareStats::class));
$app->pipe(new MiddlewareRoute($router, $container, $prototype));
$response = $app->process($request, new MiddlewareNotFound($prototype));
```

надеюсь слишком много пояснять не нужно?

Comment: если я правильно понял из документации Zend\Stratigility, они предлагают использовать посредников вместо контроллеров. Я же хотел достичь того, чтобы маршруты обрабатывались контроллерами, но была возможность перед ними "поставить" посредника при необходимости

Comment: @LivAlex, добавляется один посредник (в моём примере `MiddlewareRoute`) который дальше запускает нужный контроллер (исходя из маршрута). У `$app->pipe($path, $middleware = null)` можно указать маршрут, на котором он будет действовать. Таким образом на путь `/admin/` можно навесить посредник `AuthBasic`, например.